# when i want to update a column without non numeric values in oracle 9i

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

in a table a column contains multiple records with both numeric and non-numeric values so i'm trying to update the all records without non-numeric values

```
update tablename set columnname=to_number(regexp_replace(columnname,'\D',''));
```

the above query working successfully on `oracle 11g` version but not working in `oracle 9i` getiing error like

```
ora-00904 redexp_replace invalid identifire
```

how can i update all records 
what is replacement of  `regexp_replace`  in `oracle 9i`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723925/how-can-i-know-which-values-are-numeric-in-oracle-9i?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle 10g** introduced regular expression functions REGEXP_SUBSTR, REGEXP_REPLACE, REGEXP_INSTR and REGEXP_LIKE so they will not work in Oracle 9i.

You can instead use 2 [TRANSLATE()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TRANSLATE.html#GUID-80F85ACB-092C-4CC7-91F6-B3A585E3A690) calls to a) locate all non-digits used, then b) strip all those non-digit characters leaving just the digits:

```
select
       translate (mix_string,'x0123456789','x') non_digits
     , translate (mix_string,'0'||translate (mix_string,'x0123456789','x'),'0') only_digits
from (
     select '1a2b3c4d5e6f7h8i9j0k' mix_string
     from dual
       union all
     select '1amn2bxd3clp4d5e(*^(&6f7hsaxz8i9j0k' mix_string
     from dual
     )

|    |        NON_DIGITS         | ONLY_DIGITS |
|----|---------------------------|-------------|
|  1 | abcdefhijk                |  1234567890 |
|  2 | amnbxdclpde(*^(&fhsaxzijk |  1234567890 |
```

see: http://rextester.com/EMS52462

Answer (score 0):

since error says ora-00904 redexp_replace invalid identifire   ... so may be using redexp_replace instead of regexp_replace (misplace of d instead of g)